# app namespace not found in styles.xml in res folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I'm writing my own toolbar with an android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar widget and I want to put as much as possible into a styles.xml in my res folder.

Part of a file in /res/layout/$example.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_show_addresses_simple"
    app:style="@style/toolbar_dark" >
```

my "toolbar_dark" is defined as follows in a
/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="toolbar_dark">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/myPrimary</item>
    <item name="app:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
    <item name="app:popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="app:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

When compiling

```
  Output:
     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:contentInsetStart'.
     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:popupTheme'.
     Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:theme'.
```

If I use the app:* values in $example.xml directly everything works fine.
Therefore, how can I use my app namespace in files in the res folder?

Comment: Use style="@style/toolbar_dark" in place of app:style="@style/toolbar_dark". Remove app prefix from style.

Comment: Try Atheas suggestion first, because I also have never seen the style attribute with a prefix. However, I also never got elements with app prefix to work inside style. Even after adding `xmlns:app=...` namespace declaration to my style file.

Comment: You can use `android` name space, replace `app` with `android`

Comment: @OneWorld Just removing the app namespace in styles.xml works :-) I have to admit, I'm really confused about how to declare something in `/res/*.xml` files...

Comment: @Athena Removing `app:` in front of style is the right way to declare, but had no effect on my error.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can't use an app namespace in your style file, and you should refer to `style` attribute wihtout app namespace in your layout.

You can do somenthing like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_show_addresses_simple"
        style="@style/toolbar_dark" >
```

Style:

```
<style name="toolbar_dark" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, removing the "app" namespace worked fine.
Of course the "app:" in front of style was not necessary, too. I really needed some sleep :-)

Is there some kind of documentation on which attributes to declare in what way when moving them from a /layout/* file to a /res/* file? Should I open a new question for that?

Comment: this solution does not work for me. Although I have the same exact problem

Answer (score -6):

Use `Android` replace `app` in style file:

```
<style name="toolbar_dark">
   <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:background">@color/myPrimary</item>
   <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
   <item name="android:popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
   <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It also works with removing the app namespace altogether.
Is there a benefit in using the `android` namespace?

Comment: For Android 3.0 and higher need `android` namespace, look [style actionbar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: I'm not using an actionbar, I'm using a toolbar (without `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` )
With the support librarys it works just fine.

I guess I would need the `android` namespace if I would use the attributes without the support library :-)

Comment: Not helpful, just removing the app namespace works fine in the styles.xml file.