# How to change item text color from a NavigationDrawer menu using styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, navigation-drawer

I have a Styles.xml file describing the colors of my NavigationDrawer:

```
  <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#880ACE0A</item>
    </style>
```

I know that you should change this property of NavigationDrawer for the text colour: "app:itemTextColor", so I tried adding it to my styles.xml file:

```
  <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#880ACE0A</item>
        <item name="app:itemTextColor">#880ACE0A</item>
    </style>
```

After adding it I have this compilation error on the file styles.xml:

```
Error:(12, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:itemTextColor'.
```

How to set the colour of the text on the items of a NavigationDrawer menu?

### Edit

This is my NavigationDrawer:

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
```

And this is my drawer_menu.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

### Edit 2

I believe this is not a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790055/app-namespace-not-found-in-styles-xml-in-res-folder) because it is mandatory for this case to specify the color in styles.xml file.

Comment: please @random random delete your posible duplicate from this question, it is not the same, i need to specify it in my style.xml file. It is mandatory

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790055/app-namespace-not-found-in-styles-xml-in-res-folder

Comment: thank you companion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NullPointerException

in the styles.xml file just use the item name without the custom tag.
For example:

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#880ACE0A</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">#880ACE0A</item>
</style>
```

Cheers