# How to set vector drawables in styles.xml

Tags: android

I am setting my icon in an ImageButton like this:

```
<ImageButton
        style="@style/LeafPlayerMediaButton.Like"
        ... />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="LeafPlayerMediaButton.Like">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_app_heart_border</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_like</item>
    </style>
```

`@drawable/ic_app_heart_border` was PNG files. However, now I upgraded to vector drawables. I know that if I set a vector drawable into an ImageView I should use `app:srcCompat=@drawable/ic_app_heart_border`.

While using vector drawables,if I use:

```
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_app_heart_border</item>
```

the app crashes for API < 21.

And if I use:

```
    <item name="app:srcCompat">@drawable/ic_app_heart_border</item>
```

the app don't even start saying that `app:srcCompat` is not valid. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the 'app:' part of your styles.xml item.

So it'd be:

```
<item name="srcCompat">@drawable/ic_app_heart_border</item>
```

Any items with custom namespaces (anything other than 'android' and 'tools') should have their name space removed when put into styles.

Comment: Great. Now you answered me, I figured out the right way to ask the question, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793632/8383332).