# Assign attributes such as app:strokeWidth in style

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to create a style 100% equal to this button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_xml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
    android:text="In XML"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:cornerRadius="25dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/black" 
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"/>
```

This is the style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="btn_xml" value="btn_xml" />

    <style name="ProgrammaticallyStyle">
        <item name="android:id">@id/btn_xml</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:text">In XML</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="app:cornerRadius">25dp</item>
        <item name="app:strokeColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="app:strokeWidth">2dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But in style, the last 3 attributes start with app:xxx and cannot be assigned. I assumed that is because in xml I have the following sentence in button parent view:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Using sttributes without app: doesn't work, do I maybe need a specific parent for the style?
How can I assign these app:xxx attributes in style?

Comment: You don't use the `app` namespace prefix there; e.g., just `<item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28790055

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks but it still throw "Cannot resolve stymbol strokeWidth", maybe I need a specific parent for the style

Comment: Technically, you don't need to, but if Android Studio is complaining about it, you can simply add `parent=""`. I thought that'd be giving you a different error, though. You might just need to clean your project (under the Build menu), 'cause recent versions of AS have a real problem tracking and reconciling resource changes.

Comment: @MikeM. Genius! Just by cleaning project it worked! Thanks!